# Logic diagram for p ∨ ¬(q ∧ ¬r)

Tags: logic

I'm learning logic diagrams and a question asks to turn p ∨ ¬(q ∧ ¬r) into its respective diagram form

I came up with:
[image]

I don't feel like this is correct though. I think maybe I was supposed to find a better equivalent for ¬(q ∧ ¬r)?

Is that correct for the inverter? is an inverter a NOT?

Comment: Yes, an inverter is a NOT. It looks like there's an inverter missing...

Comment: Would I place one before the r going into the AND?

Comment: What is your problem? I've trouble in understanding.

Comment: Is the diagram correct for the expression `p ∨ ¬(q ∧ ¬r)`

Comment: Unless you're allowed to have `¬r` directly as an input, you might want instead to have just `r` going into an inverter.